# Trying to make long range LED indicator light which works on vibration

Tags: batteries

I've found a kit which works a light off sound or vibration (switchable.)

I want to replace the small light bulb with a single or 3 LED module.

The battery on the kit is a 9V, the bulb looks to be a cheap flashlight bulb.

The LEDs I want to use are Cree, for long distance, their specfications are:

- Max Drive Current: Up to 1500mA
- Typ. Forward Voltage: 2.8V @ 350mA

Can I use the 9V battery which comes on the kit or do I need to replace it with some other array/voltage of batteries, AA/AAA?
Should I use an LED bulb with different specifications?

I would like the bulb to last a few hours at least or a day if possible.

Comment: Even the "best" 9V batteries will last only about 20 minutes when supplying a current of 1A, (see [here](https://www.powerstream.com/9V-Alkaline-tests.htm), for example), and their voltage will drop below what it takes to drive three of those LEDs in series even sooner.

Answer (score 2):

A 9V battery is typically a so called ["transistor battery."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-volt_battery)

They are designed to provide low current at nine volts.  A couple of hundred milliamperes would be a typical maximum load.

The LEDs you have chosen require up to 1.5 amperes.  That's about seven times the current  that a 9V battery is intended to deliver.

If you try to power those LEDs from a nine volt battery, you will be disappointed.  You will either not get very much light out of them (if you design your circuit to limit the current to 200 milliamperes,) or you will drain the battery in minutes (if you try to get maximum brightness out of your LEDs.)

You will need a better power source than the 9V battery, and you will need something better than your existing device to control the LEDs.

It is unlikely that your existing device would be able to drive those LEDs at all, though.  The control circuit wouldn't have been designed with the high current for the LEDs in mind, and wouldn't have any kind of current limiting to protect the LEDs.

It is probably possible to adapt your existing device, but it would probably be just as easy to design a new one that is intended to work with high current LEDs .

Without the circuit or the device in hand, there's not much anyone can do for you.

Comment: What if I used just 1 HD Led and wired it to one of the large 6V flashlight batteries? The board in question is not wired for this, so guess it's a bust. Guess I'll be resigned to putting together a MAK telescope, better to see what I want up close, than a flashing light from a distance. Thanks to ALL.